# HTML Form (Bootstrap) has Wrong Indentation

Tags: html, css

I am working through a Web Development book, and part of the hands-on practice has me developing a form. All of the form controls and the button are supposed to be aligned, but for some reason each form control gets increasingly indented, and I don't know why.

Here is the relevant portions of my HTML and CSS (I can provide the whole documents if needed). Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<main>
    <h2>Contact Path of Light Yoga Studio</h2>

    <p>Required information is marked with an asterisk (*).</p>

    <form method="post" action="http://webdevbasics.net/scripts/yoga.php">
        <label for="myName">*Name:</label>
        <input required type="text" name="myName">

        <label for="myEmail">*E-Mail:</label>
        <input required type="email" name="myEmail">

        <label for="myComments">*Comments:</label>
        <textarea required name="myComments" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>

        <button id="mySubmit">Send Now</button>

    </form>

</main>
```

CSS:

```
    * { box-sizing: border-box; }
    
    main {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 2em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        margin-left: 170px;
    }
    
    label{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 10em;
        padding: 1em;
    }
    
    input, textarea{
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }
    
    form{
        padding: 3em;
        
    }

    #mySubmit{
        margin-left: 12em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `padding` property of your `label` class in the CSS. Try removing that property or reduce it from `1em` to maybe `0.5em` and see if that helps. It's probably overflowing due to too much padding.

Comment: Yeah, that did it, thanks! It looks like it was specifically the top padding, too.